# How to write xpath for Dynamic ID/Webelement?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate "Login" button for this website link-[monsterIndia Login](https://my.monsterindia.com/login.html?src=http://my.monsterindia.com/my_monster.html&rand=5257) but the xpath of the Login button keeps on changing. I am mentioning the xpaths which i had used

-First XPath-

```
html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/input,
```

Second XPath-

```
html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/div[1]/input
```

but when i tried to locate it for third time it again changed to

```
.//*[@id='contact_']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/input
```

HTML Code -

```
        <tbody>
         <tr>
         <tr>
         <tr>
         <tr>
         <tr>
         <tr>
         <tr>
        <td class="font_11" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <div style="float:left">
        <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;">
        <input width="54" type="image" height="23" border="0" value="" name="submit"  src="https://media4.monsterindia.com//monster_2012/btn_login.jpg"/>
        </div>
```

In the HTML Code the number of tr is changing from 7 and 8 also the div is changing from 1 and 2
I am attaching the screen shot of the entire HTML code[image]

Comment: There are static & unique values there though, for instance it's an `input` that has a static `src`.

Comment: @Arran Arran is it the correct way to find an element for the same website which i had mentioned in the code above. Xpath<<=>>window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/trans.gif']")).click();. I am asking this because after putting this xpath in my code i got ElementNotVisibleException Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very bad practise to use absolute xpath in automation to locate element.Instead of using absolute xpath you can use relative xpath.

Login button locators

xpath

```
By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")
```

cssSelector

```
By.cssSelector("[name='submit']")
```

Comment: @Santoshsharrma Sir, is this the correct way to locate an element Xpath<<>> window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/trans.gif']")).click();.

Comment: Correct only. You can use contains also. By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'media')]")